# The C++ compiler doesn't work after MinGW is installed？

Tags: c++, mingw, gnu

I'm a C++ new learner and want to set my PC to learn coding. But the compiler doesn't work after all the MinGW packages were installed, and it doesn't show what goes wrong. How can I get it work?

I'm using Windows 10 (64 Bit).

All the MinGW packages were installed:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pE8gI.png)

The Path was setted:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niyXA.png)

Use g++ -v to test, it's Ok, on the cmd it shows:

C:\Users\shaun\Documents\cpp>g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../src/gcc-6.3.0/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --with-gmp=/mingw --with-mpfr=/mingw --with-mpc=/mingw --with-isl=/mingw --prefix=/mingw --disable-win32-registry --target=mingw32 --with-arch=i586 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --with-pkgversion='MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1' --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-threads --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --enable-libstdcxx-debug --with-tune=generic --enable-libgomp --disable-libvtv --enable-nls
Thread model: win32
gcc version 6.3.0 (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1)

**But it doesn't work:**
C:\Users\shaun\Documents\cpp>g++ 1.cpp

C:\Users\shaun\Documents\cpp>g++ 2.cpp

C:\Users\shaun\Documents\cpp>

1.cpp is just a HelloWorld:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
std::cout << "Hello, World!";
return 0;
}
```

2.cpp is a simple loop:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n ;
    cout<<"please input the height"<<endl;
    cin >> n; 

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n - i -1; j++)
        {
            cout<<" ";
        }
        for (int j = 0; j <= 2 * i; j++)
        {
            if (j == 0 or j == 2 * i)
                cout<<"*";
            else
                cout<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        {
            cout<<" ";
        }
        for (int j = 0; j <= 2 * ( n - i - 2 ); j++)
        {
            if (j == 0 or j == 2 * ( n - i - 2 ))
                cout<<"*";
            else
                cout<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you know it didn't work? What did you do to run the program? What was the output of that?

Comment: Don't post images of text! Copy-paste it as text into the question itself instead. Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: As for your problem, how do you know it didn't work? Have you checked that there's no `a.exe` file generated? What if you list all files in the directory after building?

Comment: @Galik cause it shows no output it the cmd, normally it daoes on the other computers.

Comment: You have not shown the command to **run** the program. In your examples you only **compile** the program. Doing `g++ 1.cpp` simply creates the program. You then need to actually run it.

Comment: To give the program a meaningful name use `g++ -o program.exe 1.cpp`

Comment: To run it do: `./program.exe`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for the tips, it's been edited. Cause it shows no output it the cmd, normally it daoes on the other computers. Yes, there's a a.exe file. In the directory there're three files: 1.cpp, 2.cpp and a.exe

Comment: thank you @Galik, I got the ouput on the cmd simply use a.exe, but when I use ./a.exe I got the feedback says: '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.  How comes that?

Comment: [tag:compiler-construction] is for questions about writing compilers, not using them. Thanks for your co-operation.

Comment: _"normally it [does] on the other computers"_ Nope, all C++ compilers work this way.

Comment: @Shaun2049 _"How comes that?"_ Galik accidentally gave you Linux-style instructions.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you are right, earlier I used the uni's computer, which is Linux system. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building and running a C++ program is a multi-step process:

1. Edit code
2. Compile code into object file(s)
3. Link object file(s) (and libraries) into executable program
4. Run executable program.

For simple programs (like yours) step 2 and 3 can be combined, like you do.

The problem you're having is that you don't do step 4, you only build the executable file but you never run it.

If you don't explicitly specify an output file name, the executable program should be named `a.exe`, which you need to run:

```
> g++ 1.cpp
> a.exe
```

---

Note that when you then build `2.cpp` you will overwrite `a.exe` with the new program.

If you want to name the executable file to something else, you need to use the `-o` option:

```
> g++ 1.cpp -o 1.exe
> g++ 2.cpp -o 2.exe
```

Now you have two different programs, `1.exe` and `2.exe`, each created from different source files.

Comment: It's very kind of you! Now I get the outputs on the cmd. Thanks a lot : )